# TransformToVisual to element in a different visual tree within the same window

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, drag-and-drop, transform

This is related to some custom drag and drop functionality I am implementing.

Everything was working very well until I threw a ContentPresenter into the mix.

I have a Window which contains a ContentPresenter.

The Content of this ContentPresenter is Bound different usercontrols which are popped in and out dynamically.

The problem I'm having is I need to perform a TransformToVisual on a control contained within the ContentPresenter relative to a control that lives outside in the main window where this COntentPresenter resides.

Summary:

Window -> Canvas called MyCanvas -> ContenPresenter (Content Presenter contains a ListView called MyListView)

I want to call MyListView.TransformToVisual(MyCanvas).

This is seemingly not allowed as I receive the error: "The specified Visual and this Visual do not share a common ancestor, so there is no valid transformation between the two Visuals."

Notes on snippet below:
  1. _targetBoundingBoxes is a List of UIElements which should accept a drag
  2. As I drag, I move a canvas around the screen (_canvasThatIsBeingDraggedAround).
  3. As it moves, I am querying to see if the current MousePosition falls within any of the _dropTargets.

Code snippet that is failing:

```
  _targetBoundingBoxes.Clear();
  foreach (var item in _dropTargets)
  {
    GeneralTransform t = item.TransformToVisual(_canvasThatIsBeingDraggedAround);
    Rect _dropBoundingBox = t.TransformBounds(new Rect(0, 0, item.RenderSize.Width, item.RenderSize.Height));
    _targetBoundingBoxes.Add(item, _dropBoundingBox);
  }
<Window>
    <StackPanel>
        <Button Margin="0,50,0,0" Height="50"/>
        <ContentPresenter Name="HI" Content="{Binding Blah}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>



      //Create a canvas which will be used as the dragged adorner.  Canvas is used since you can set the Left and Top positions.
  if (_topWindow.FindName("adornerLayer") == null)
  {
    //grab the existingContent
    UIElement existingContent = (UIElement)_topWindow.Content;

    //create a Grid wrapper around the entire window content so we can add the new canvas adornerLayer as a child in addition to the existing content
    Grid nonLayoutCanvas = new Grid(); nonLayoutCanvas.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Stretch; nonLayoutCanvas.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Stretch;

    //create the hidden Canvas that we will draw to and move around the screen
    Canvas adornerCanvas = new Canvas(); adornerCanvas.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed; adornerCanvas.Name = "adornerLayer";
    adornerCanvas.Effect = new DropShadowEffect() { ShadowDepth = 5, BlurRadius = 5, Color = Colors.Silver };

    //reset the content to the nonLayout Canvas
    _topWindow.Content = nonLayoutCanvas;

    //add the original content and the new canvas to the grid above
    nonLayoutCanvas.Children.Add(existingContent);
    nonLayoutCanvas.Children.Add(adornerCanvas);

    _topWindow.RegisterName("adornerLayer", adornerCanvas);
  }

  _canvasThatIsBeingDraggedAround = (Canvas)_topWindow.FindName("adornerLayer");
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `TransformToVisual` to `TransformToAncestor`.

Comment: Thanks...I tried as well and I receive "The specified Visual is not an ancestor of this Visual".

This error is odd to me because the Visual lives inside of a ContentPresenter which itself lives inside of a Window

Comment: Where do you get `_canvasThatIsBeingDraggedAround` and `item` from?

Comment: _canvasThatIsBeingDraggedAround is created at runtime and added to the owning Window.  This is ensure that I have a canvas.

Hmmm...maybe you're onto something there.  I'm doing a RegisterName 
on it.

Added some more code...

Also...item is determined by reading in an attachedProperty set in XAML.  Basically consumer says "DragDropUtil.DragDropTargets="name1,name2,etc...".

I then read those in an keep track

Those are found via FindName

Comment: I would suggest try using Snoop to inspect the running application and check what the visual tree looks like, and what's the relation between these different elements.

Comment: thanks a lot for your feedback and your time.  Appreciate it.  I'm going to give Snoop a shot.

Comment: Did you ever find a fix for this? I'm having the same issue and the child element is a direct child of the parent that I'm trying to use this with